# Inequality of two numbers

Tags: inequality

The question is
"For two consecutive multiples of 5, the smaller number is greater than half of the larger one.  Find the least values of these two number."

I am stuck!

Comment: $10$ and $15$ ..

Answer (score 2):

The numbers are of the form $5x$ and $5x+5$. We are given that
$$5x> \dfrac{5x+5}2 \implies 10x > 5x + 5 \implies x > 1$$
Hence, the minimum two consecutive multiples of five are $10$ and $15$.

Comment: I thought the numbers are x and 5x
THanks!

Comment: @user256670: Note that you can avoid that confusion by stating precisely what $x$ means before you use it. Is it the actual first number, or the multiplier of $5$ used to form the first number? In this case it is the multiplier, so the numbers are $5x$ and $5x+5$. (If $x$ were the actual first number, the two numbers would be $x$ and $x+5$, not $x$ and $5x$.)

Answer (score 0):

> "For two consecutive multiples of 5, the smaller number is greater than half of the larger one. Find the least values of these two number."

Let's analyze this question.

> For two consecutive multiples of 5,

So the two numbers in terms of $(5x, 5y)$, where $x$ is the smaller number and $y$ is the larger number, must be $(5, 10)$, $(10, 15)$, etc.

> the smaller number is greater than half of the larger one.

$5x>5y/2$

> Find the least values of these two number.[sic]

So we must find $x$.

Now let us go about finding the answer.

First, let us look at $(1, 2)$.

$(1*5, 2*5)=(5, 10)$

$5>10/2$

$5>5$

This inequality is not true.  This is not the answer.

Now let's look at $(2, 3)$.

$(2*5, 3*5)=(10, 15)$

$10>15/2$

$10>7.5$

This inequality is true.  Therefore, $x>1$.

Comment: GREAT!  THANKS!!

Comment: You're very welcome!